# How to set tab values in a template in C# (Need to set value PDF template in Docusign)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

```
        TemplateRole templateRole = new TemplateRole();
        templateRole.Email = "chetan.wani88@gmail.com";
        templateRole.RoleName = "Developer";
        templateRole.DefaultRecipient = "true";
        templateRole.Name = "Month Year 2021";

        //templateRole.Tabs.TitleTabs.Add(new Title { TabLabel = "title", Value = "1323232" });

        templateRole.ClientUserId = string.Empty;
      

        templateRole.Tabs = new Tabs();
        templateRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
        
        templateRole.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.AnchorXOffset = "20";
        signHere.AnchorYOffset = "10";
        signHere.AnchorUnits = "pixels";

        templateRole.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

        Text textTab = new Text();
        textTab.TabLabel = "Test88";
        textTab.Value = "12525252";
        templateRole.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(textTab);
```

List templateRoles = new List();
templateRoles.Add(templateRole);

envDef.TemplateRoles = templateRoles;

envDef.Status = "sent";

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

Answer (score 0):

Please read our [article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/) on this subject that includes code snippets in C# and other langs.
The code must match the recipients, since the tabs are associated with them. Often the tabs don't show up because you added a new recipient that has a different role.

```
templateRole.RoleName = "Developer";
```

|This must match your template.